# .modal-content for different Modals (react-bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I'm using the [Modal-component from react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal).

I have two different Modals in my application and I want **one of them** to have an orange background color.

I can achieve the orange background color by doing:

```
.modal-content {
  background: #FF8C0A;
}
```

However, this will make both of the modals in my application orange. I can't find a way to label the modal-content with an unique ID to edit just one of them. Can the "dialogClassName" prop maybe be used in some way?

**Note:** I've already tried giving the head and body IDs and making their background color orange. This works on desktop, however, on mobile devices there is a transparent line between the header and body in which doesn't look good.

Thank you!

[Screenshot of the implementation of the Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hQES.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS nesting to target children of the components, For eg, In your case,

You named your modal using `dialogClassName` prop to `info-modal`, you can use this in ur CSS

```
info-modal .modal-content {
  background: #FF8C0A;
}
```

Similarly for other modals, you can pass different name using `dialogClassName` prop

```
other-modal-1 .modal-content {
  background: red;
}

other-modal-2 .modal-content {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: amazing. this helped me out too!

Comment: What if you are using `CSS Modules` and you are trying to target generated class name of `React Bootstrap`? Example the `modal-content`. How am I able to add the generated `CSS Module` unique tag name to `modal-content` so I can design it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CSS modules" package for achieving this.

There are useful links for learning and implementing CSS modules..

- https://www.javascriptstuff.com/css-modules-by-example/
- https://css-modules.github.io/webpack-demo/

Answer (score 0):

set  `backdropClassName="red"` in your modal

and in CSS

```
.red {
    background: none !important;
}
```